# Updating a git branch that was created from a branch other than master

Tags: git, branch, fetch, pull

I've been working on a feature for a project on a branch that was created from `master`, which is currently in review for merging. I'll call it `dev`. In the meantime, I created a branch out of `dev` which I'll call `branch`.

While in review, `dev` was found to need some changes, so I checked `dev` back out, made the changes, and recommitted and pushed.

Now my copy of `branch` is out of date with its source, `dev`. How do I update it? Normally, I would just do a fetch, followed by a pull. When `master` has changes, doing this causes my branch to pull in said changes, allowing me to stay up to date with the work of my peers. When I try to do this between my own branches, it says `branch` is up-to-date, which is incorrect.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

EDIT: I ended up doing a rebase as Max Friederichs describes below. It does what I specified in terms of updating `branch` with the changes from `dev`. The reason I selected Jean Rostan's answer is because doing a rebase changes the workflow history of the git repository, but doing a merge as Jean suggested merges in the new stuff from the branch and leaves the workflow history alone -- good for when you want to see what happened when.

In reality, both solutions achieve the same thing, just with different effects on the workflow history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's local branches only (which is your case), start by going on the branch you want to update:

```
git checkout branch
```

Then merge local changes from the target branch:

```
git merge dev
```

and it will merge `dev` into `branch`, that is to say update it.

When you do a pull, you retrieve upstream changes (in your remote repo); thus no changes are found if no changes were made on the branch `branch` in your remote repo.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `rebase` your `branch` ... branch so that it includes the latest changes you made to the `dev` branch

```
git checkout branch
git rebase dev
```

This will momentarily put aside your changes on `branch`, apply missing changes from `dev`, then re apply your changes to `branch`.  Any conflicts need to be addressed at this time as well.  You will need to force push if `branch` was previously pushed.